# Php if else with ? symbol

Tags: php

I wanted to validate country

```
<option<? $nationality == 'Albania' ? echo 'selected="selected"';?> value="Albania">Albania</option>
```

I want check if var $nationality is Albania

If it is true, I want echo html code selected="selected"

Is there anything wrong with my code

I get an error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO
```

Comment: put the else condition also ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put echo before the condition. Also the 'else' part was missing. This should do:

```
<option<? echo ($nationality == 'Albania') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?> value="Albania">Albania</option>
```

For more information, check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to first say that using short tags in PHP isn't that recommended since it's the same tag XML uses.

```
<option<?php echo ($nationality == 'Albania' ? 'selected="selected"' : '');?> value="Albania">Albania</option>
```

I changed this up so it will echo the value with the shorthand returning the variable. The reason it didn't work is because the shorthand requires the `:` for the else statement.

Also, since this appears to be a country list, you can save a lot of time by doing a loop of the values.

```
<?php
   $nationality = "Country1";
   $countries = array('Country1','Country2');
   echo '<select>';
   foreach($countries as $country) {
      echo '<option value="'.$country.'"'.($nationality == $country ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$country.'</option>';

      // This below line is just for formatting. It can be removed;
      echo "\n";
   }
   echo '</select>';
?>
```

**Code Output**

```
<select>
   <option value="Country1" selected="selected">Country1</option>
   <option value="Country2">Country2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to finish properly your ternary operator and add `echo` before it.
This is what you should do:

```
<option<? echo $nationality == 'Albania' ? echo 'selected="selected"' : '';?> value="Albania">Albania</option>
```

Comment: As pointed above, the second 'echo' should be omitted since it would produce an error.